# Regular Expression Program

Tags: java, regex, string

Hi I have the following text:

```
SMWABCCA
ABCCAEZZRHM
NABCCAYJG 
XABCCA
ABCCADK
ABCCASKIYRH 
ABCCAKY 
PQABCCAK    
ABCCAKQ
```

This method takes a regex in out by the user and SHOULD print out the Strings it applies to but seems to print out something completely different:

```
private void matchIt(String regex) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = null;        
        boolean found = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            m = p.matcher(data[i]);
            if(m.find()){
                out.println(data[i]);
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if(!found){
            out.println("Pattern Not Found");
        }
    }
```

When inputting "[C],

EDIT: Sorry I printed out the wrong output. Here is the actual output:

```
SMWABCCA
ABCCAEZZRHM
NABCCAYJG
XABCCA
ABCCADK
ABCCASKIYRH
ABCCAKY
PQABCCAK
ABCCAKQ
SMWABCCA
ABCCAEZZRHM
NABCCAYJG
XABCCA
ABCCADK
ABCCASKIYRH
ABCCAKY
PQABCCAK
ABCCAKP
```

Any ideas why? I think I'm using m.find() improperly...

EDIT: What would the regular expression be for find all strings that end with P:

I tried:

[.*P][\W]

Which I interpret to be - All anything until a P followed by non word characters..but it doesn't work.

Comment: The output is correct. Those are all the strings that contain a 'C'.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Can you show how `matchIt` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of Matcher looks OK to me.  My guess is that your application is calling `matchIt` twice for each regex.

Comment: Thanks, I reworked my code. Am new to regexes so not sure if I was applying it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

regex `[C]` lokks for character `C` in a sting and obviously every of your stings contains it